# Writing content of a Dataset into a JSON-String

Tags: java, apache-spark

We can write the content of a [dataset](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html) into a Json file:

```
DataSet<...> dataset = ...
dataset.write().json("myFile");
```

Assuming the dataset is small enough, is there a way to write the content directly into a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), a [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) or any kind of [OutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html)?

It is possible to write the dataset into a temporary folder and then read the data again:

```
Path tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("tempfiles");
String tempFile = tempDir.toString() + "/json";
dataset.coalesce(1).write().json(tempFile);        
Path jsonFile = Files.find(Paths.get(tempFile), 1, (path, basicFileAttributes) -> {
    return Files.isRegularFile(path) && path.toString().endsWith("json");
}).findFirst().get();
BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(jsonFile);
reader.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
```

But is there a better way to achieve the same result without using the indirection of an intermediate file?

Comment: You can transform your Dataset[A] into a Dataset[String] just by mapping your data. Your function would convert A to its json representation (as String for instance). You can use Jackson to achieve this since it's included with Spark dependencies.

Comment: Why do you need to use Spark if you're just going to collect the data anyway to a local string/stream?

Comment: @baitmbarek Thank you for that advice. Do you want to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have a huge Spark application and I want to do some post-processing on the aggregated results of the Spark logic

Comment: But you don't need to collect all your data back into a single machine to do that do you?

Comment: No, I dont. Just a very small (aggregated) part of the data will be sent to the driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform your Dataset[A] into a Dataset[String] just by mapping your data.

Your function would convert A to its Json representation (as String for instance).

You can use Jackson to achieve this since it's included with Spark dependencies.